# Move div outwards from a card fan, based on it's rotation?

Tags: javascript, css, transform

I am making a hand of cards fan out. When hovering over a card i want it to move outwards so it looks like you're pulling it out.

Like this:
[image: cardfan]
The rotation of the cards is made in javascript by "90 / amount of cards" 90 being the angle of the maximum rotation. That way i know the angle of each card.
The hover would preferably be done in 100% css but javascript is fine too if that's the only way.

```js
socket.on('hand', function(hand){
    console.log("kaarten gekregen");
      var node = document.getElementById("cardwrap");
      node.innerHTML = ''; //remove all cards in the hand
      var perCardRotate = 90 / hand.length;   //calculate the rotation per card
      var perCardRotate = perCardRotate.toString().trim();
      for(var i=0; i < hand.length; i++){  //for loop to create all cards
      var subnode = document.createElement("a");
      subnode.setAttribute("class", "card");
      subnode.setAttribute("name", i);
      subnode.setAttribute("id", i);
      subnode.setAttribute("onclick", "PickCard(getAttribute('name'))");
      var textnode = document.createTextNode(hand[i]);
      var image = document.createElement("img");
      image.setAttribute("src", "/client/img/" + hand[i] + ".png");
      image.setAttribute("zIndex", i + 1000);
      image.setAttribute("id", i + "CARD")
      subnode.appendChild(image);
      node.appendChild(subnode);

      perCardRotateString = (i * perCardRotate )- 45 + (parseFloat(perCardRotate) / 2) //calculate the rotation of the current card being made
      var perCardTranslateString = (0.03 * Math.pow(perCardRotateString, 2)); //calculate how far the card needs to be moved down based on: y=(0.03 X)^2

      document.getElementById(i + "CARD").setAttribute('style', "transform: rotate("+ perCardRotateString + 'deg) translateY( '+ perCardTranslateString +'px)'); //set rotation and translation

    }
  });
```

```css
#hand{
  /* margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;*/
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  float: left;
  align-content: center;
  margin-top: 200px;
  max-width: 1180px;
  margin-left: 60px;
}

.card{
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  transition: top ease 0.5s;
  margin-left: -60px;
}

.card:hover{
  top: -20px;
}

img{
  width: 110px;
  padding-left: 4px;
  padding-right: 4px;
  padding-top: 4px;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div id="cardwrap">
    <a class="card" name="0" id="0" onclick="PickCard(getAttribute('name'))">
        <img src="/client/img/as.png" zindex="1000" id="0CARD" style="transform: rotate(-38.57142857142857deg) translateY( 44.63265306122448px)">
    </a>
    <a class="card" name="1" id="1" onclick="PickCard(getAttribute('name'))">
        <img src="/client/img/3d.png" zindex="1001" id="1CARD" style="transform: rotate(-25.714285714285708deg) translateY( 19.836734693877542px)">
    </a>
    <a class="card" name="2" id="2" onclick="PickCard(getAttribute('name'))">
        <img src="/client/img/4c.png" zindex="1002" id="2CARD" style="transform: rotate(-12.857142857142856deg) translateY( 4.959183673469386px)">
    </a>
    <a class="card" name="3" id="3" onclick="PickCard(getAttribute('name'))"><img src="/client/img/5s.png" zindex="1003" id="3CARD" style="transform: rotate(-1.7763568394002505e-15deg) translateY( 9.466330862652141e-32px)">
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide your code so that we can help

Comment: @Teemu I added the code.

Comment: @JoykalInfotech I just added it

Comment: @Baksteen-13 you have error in your code please add script..

Comment: @לבנימלכה what do you mean?.....

Comment: `"Uncaught ReferenceError: socket is not defined",`

Comment: @לבנימלכה yeah obviously it's a snippet of my javascript code. i use socket.io but you don't want me to add the whole node server in the question as that has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Basicly, for every card, do also `translateX(Math.sin(perCardRotate) * perCardTranslateString)` where `perCardRotate` is radians.

Comment: @Baksteen-13 I just create it with css and HTML:https://jsfiddle.net/xsnh578u/

Comment: @לבנימלכה no because the amount of cards is not always the same. javascript calculates the rotation of each card based on how many there are. the amount of cards can vary from 1 to 52.

Comment: it is only an example how to do `:hover` and `transform`(that the reason I did not post it as answer)

Comment: @לבנימלכה yes but if you look at the picture that is not the way the hover should work.

Comment: here is update for you:https://jsfiddle.net/xsnh578u/1/

Comment: even better version:https://jsfiddle.net/xsnh578u/2/

Comment: @לבנימלכה that's just moving cards up, not outwards

Comment: `z-index`??:https://jsfiddle.net/xsnh578u/4/

Comment: @לבנימלכה are you even trying to answer my question at this point?

Comment: finally I saw that you use my answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use CSS and Transform?

```css
#container{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:transparent;
    position:relative;
    margin:50px;
    transform:rotateX(60deg) rotateZ(45deg);
    transform-style:preserve-3d; z-index:98;
}

#container .card{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:#ddd;
    transform:rotateX(180deg) rotateZ(45deg);
    transform-style:preserve-3d;
    position:relative;
    z-index:99;
}

#container:hover .card{
    top:-50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="card">
  
  </div>
</div>
```

---

EDIT:
[@לבני מלכה](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9140740/%D7%9C%D7%91%D7%A0%D7%99-%D7%9E%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%94) commented [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xsnh578u/4/)

Here are the code from it:

```css
.wrap{
  display:flex;
  position:relative;
  justify-content: center;
}
.card{
  height:120px;
  width:80px;
  background:blue;
  border:1px solid black;
  border-radius:5px;
  position:relative;
  top:30px;
  transition: transform .2s;
}
.card:nth-child(1) {
transform: translateY(0px) rotate(-42deg);
left: 87px;
top: 52px;
}
.card:nth-child(2) {
    transform: translateY(0px) rotate(-26deg);
    left: 42px;
    top: 38px;
}
.card:nth-child(3) {
    transform: translateY(0px) rotate(-16deg);
    left: 7px;
    top: 26px;
 }
.card:nth-child(4) {
    transform: translateY(0px) rotate(1deg);
    left: -24px;
    top: 24px;  
}
.card:nth-child(5) {
    right: 54px;
    top: 28px;
    transform: translateY(0px) rotate(16deg);
}
.card:nth-child(6) {
    transform: translateY(0px) rotate(26deg);
    right: 82px;
    top: 44px;
}
.card:nth-child(7) {
    transform: translateY(0px) rotate(35deg);
    right: 117px;
    top: 67px;
}

.card:nth-child(1):hover{
z-index:2;
  transform: translate(-20px) rotate(-42deg) scale(1.5);
}

.card:nth-child(2):hover{
z-index:2;
  transform: translateY(-20px) rotate(-26deg) scale(1.5);
}
.card:nth-child(3):hover{
z-index:2;
  transform: translate(1px , -20px) rotate(-16deg) scale(1.5);
}

.card:nth-child(4):hover{
z-index:2;
  transform: translateY(-20px) rotate(1deg) scale(1.5);
}
.card:nth-child(5):hover{
z-index:2;
  transform: translate(1px , -20px) rotate(16deg) scale(1.5);
}

.card:nth-child(6):hover{
z-index:2;
  transform: translateY(-20px) rotate(26deg) scale(1.5);
}
.card:nth-child(7):hover{
z-index:2;
  transform: translate(1px , -20px) rotate(35deg) scale(1.5);
  
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
</div>
<div class="t">

</div>
```

Comment: if you copy my answer please ask for my permission :) LOLL

Comment: @לבנימלכה why would i copy your answer. its not correct

Comment: I create this fiddle by my self and this user copy and post it in his/her answer... but all good